# Display JSON results in Appcelerator

Tags: mobile, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

So I'm trying to switch to Appcelerator and am having some trouble figuring out exactly how it works. Trying to just have a simple button that loads a new window and lists some SQL entries. I'm not getting any errors, but page is showing blank. I'm certain I'm making an obvious mistake, would help if someone could point in right direction. Returned JSON array is correct.

Index.xml

```
<Alloy>
    <Window class="container">
    </Window> 
</Alloy>
```

bookdetails.js

```
<Alloy> 
   <Window class="container"> 
   </Window> 
</Alloy>
```

Index.js

```
var args = arguments;
var data = [];
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
title: 'Title goes here',
layout: 'vertical',
backgroundColor: '#123456',
});

var button = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title: 'My button',
    top: 10,
    height: 40,
    width: 200
});

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // Check console
    Ti.API.info('User clicked the button ');
    var dataview = Alloy.createController("bookdetails").getView();
    dataview.open();

});
win.add(button);
win.open();
```

bookdetails.js

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
title: 'Title goes here',
layout: 'vertical',
backgroundColor: '#123456',
});
var data = [];
var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
    xhr.onload = function(){
        var logins = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        for(var i = 0; i < logins.length; i++) {
            data.push[logins[i]];
        }
        var table = Ti.UI.createTableView({ objName: 'table' });
        for (var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++){
             var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
            className: 'row',
            objName: 'row',
             touchEnabled: true,
             height: 100
         });
  table.setData(data);
  win.add(table);
}

    };
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/check.php');
    xhr.send();

win.open();
```

Answer (score 0):

you're defining a window inside both index.xml and index.js. You should not do that.

Your index.js should look smth like this:

```
var args = arguments;
var data = [];

var button = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title: 'My button',
    top: 10,
    height: 40,
    width: 200
});

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // Check console
    Ti.API.info('User clicked the button ');
    var dataview = Alloy.createController("bookdetails").getView();
    dataview.open();

});

$.getView().add(button); // this gets the root window of controller and adds a button to it
```

and your data controller should also be refactored to something like this:

```
var data = [];
var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
    xhr.onload = function(){
        var logins = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        for(var i = 0; i < logins.length; i++) {
            data.push[logins[i]];
        }
        var table = Ti.UI.createTableView({ objName: 'table' });
        for (var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++){
             var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
            className: 'row',
            objName: 'row',
             touchEnabled: true,
             height: 100
         });
  table.setData(data);
  $.getView().add(table);
}

    };
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/check.php');
    xhr.send();
 $.getView().show();
```